# Write any set in a product sigma algebra as a product of sets

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $(\mathsf{E}, \Sigma_E)$ and $(\mathsf{F}, \Sigma_F)$ are measurable spaces, and $(\mathsf{E}\times\mathsf{F}, \Sigma_E\otimes \Sigma_F)$ their product. Given $C\in \Sigma_E\otimes \Sigma_F$ can I always write
$$
C = A\times B
$$
where $A\in\Sigma_E$ and $B\in\Sigma_F$?

Answer (score 1):

No. Work out an example where $E$ and $F$ are finite sets (two elements in each will do) and the sigma fields are the full power sets.